# How to run .jar file via powershell script

Tags: powershell, jar, scripting

I want to run agent.jar file for my jenkins agent via powershell script the scenario is that in one jenkins job "Reboot Agent" the agent rebooted successfully , after reboot I want to start another job which connect agent to master via powershell script

This is my script but somehow it does not works and i can not see my agent going online nor any error pops up

I am using powershell ISE for executing my script

```
Start-Process java -ArgumentList “-jar agent.jar -jnlp Url http://localhost:8080/computer/ComputerName/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret 338e93b0b127faf70a56c0edec39a70804accd7157c49e1e37e3be14aa8ea8db" -Filepath "C:\Jenkins"
```

Can any one help with script Thanks.

Comment: Try this (as-is, without `Start-Process`): `java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://localhost:8080/computer/ComputerName/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret 338e93b0b127faf70a56c0edec39a70804accd7157c49e1e37e3be14aa8ea8db`

Comment: Thanks for the reply , when I removed Start-Process I got this error instead
java : Unrecognized option: -ArgumentList

Comment: Copy the command from my comment. There is no ArgumentList parameter. Also note that it is `-jnlpUrl`, not `-jnlp Url`.

Comment: sorry for re questioning from your command there is not file path ?

Comment: You mean `-FilePath`? That is a parameter of `Start-Process`, which is not needed.

Comment: i exactly copied your command and I got an error which i suspect that its says
java : Error: Unable to access jarfile agent.jar may be bc of i removed filepath location ???

Comment: Do you run the command in the directory, where `agent.jar` is located? Otherwise specify full path to `agent.jar`, e. g. `-jar "C:\Jenkins\agent.jar"`.